# how to erase an image drawn by canvas?

Tags: android

```
  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      Log.d("dd","draw");

            mBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.image1);

            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, srcRect,dstRect,null);
            mBitmaps=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.paintball);
              canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmaps, 180,200,null);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK)
```

or to your bg color.